# Back button retains previous dynamically generated page contents in Iphone Browser but not on Desktop Browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, back-button

I have a PHP/MySQL/Ajax generated page which lists several questions.  You can search for specific questions, or click on a tag to list questions associated with that tag.  So this page generates custom lists through Ajax.

When I click on a question, it brings me to another separate page.

When I click on the back button, I get two different behaviors:

1. On the IOS Iphone Browser, the back button brings me to the previous list page with exactly what was custom loaded (WHAT I WANT).  This is good because it maintains the context of the user and what he was doing previously.  It does not regenerate the page from scratch, losing its custom list.
2. On my desktop browser (Chrome, IE), the list page regenerates and it starts from scratch again (NOT WHAT I WANT) and the user loses his position and context of his original intent.

What is going on between the IOS Browser and the other Desktop Browsers?

How do I get the desktop browsers to behave the same way as the IOS browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because this is just a suggestion, but perhaps since you're already using AJAX calls, why not render the lists in a different view on the same page, and then give the user the ability to exit out of that view and return right back to the search.  You could do this with just a couple divs, some CSS styling, and a little bit of JavaScript.  This is a more dynamic approach that will help you in the future, as well, and it's known as a SPA.  You won't have to deal with the quirky behavior of the back button this way, either. Just a suggestion.

Comment: And I meant to give you this link, which shows a single page application at work. It's a wonderful thing not having to go back and forth between pages. And your users will thank you for it. https://demo.tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework/#

Comment: @Marcus - yes, great suggestion and I have done this with other pages - works very well, except instinctively the user likes to automatically click on back or the back button on the mouse and expects it to go back to where he came from with the same context - but then does not, but brings to previous unrelated page.  Not sure if you can mask the back button to behave differently as I think this is a browser function?

Comment: The only control you have over the back button (and refreshing a page) is to use `window.onbeforeunload` in which you can just do something like this: `window.onbeforeunload = function () { return true; }`.  What this will do is cause the user to see a dialog box that asks them if they want to leave and that their changes may not be saved.  It acts as a preventative measure for when you want to warn users that they might be leaving behind valuable content that hasn't been saved yet.  The thing is, though, you can't out-program the user, no matter how hard you try.

Comment: Btw, you can try that piece of code on this very page by just pasting it into the developer console of your browser and then trying to go back or refresh. You'll see a popup display asking you if you're sure you want to leave.

Comment: I still have a curiosity as to why the IOS Browser behaves differently for the back button, actually preserving exactly what the previous dynamically generated page load was ...?

Comment: I couldn't find much information on it, but a hunch of mine is that the iOS browser is spinning up a new instance (much like a new tab) when you navigate to the new page, and then when you go back, you're leaving the newly created instance and just going back to the state of the page as it was when you left it.  In the browser, however, pressing the back button attempts to reload the resources of the URL entirely (minus caching and a few other quirks), since you're not going back to the same state that you left.